# How to check the lenght of an array of strings? I don't want to use lenght() because I need to know how many strings are in the array

Tags: java

```
public class Programma{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Il numero di parole uguali a Ciao è: " + contaparola(args));
        }

    static int contaparola(String array[]){
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<array.lenght; ++i){
            if (array[i].equals("Ciao"))
                ++counter;
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Programma.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                for (int i=0; i<array.lenght; ++i){
                                     ^
  symbol:   variable lenght
  location: variable array of type String[]
1 error
```

Why? I dont want to use `lenght()` because I don't want to know the *lenght* of the string, but I actually want to know how many strings are in the array.

Comment: `array.length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.length` isn't the length of a string.  It's the length of an array, or "the number of items that could be stored in the array.

The main problem in your program is that you misspelled `length`.

Comment: @Mnkisd Don't worry, we have all been there.  Good luck on the rest of your project